# KDB: Loop over 2 lists and filter/replace

Tags: kdb

In KDB+ I have 2 lists of equal size, where I want to replace(probably use ssr ) strings in list1 conditioned on the values in list2.

```
list1:("Boy";"Toy";"Coy";"Poy")
list2:("A","B","A","B")
```

If list2[i]=="B" replace "oy" by "ab"
So we should finally get

```
list1:("Boy";"Tab";"Coy";"Pab")
```

Answer (score 4):

```
q)list1:("Boy";"Toy";"Coy";"Poy");
q)list2:"ABAB";
q)@[list1;where list2="B";ssr[;"oy";"ab"]]
"Boy"
"Tab"
"Coy"
"Pab"
```

Comment: they're equivalent, I'd have a read through this section of q for mortals, https://code.kx.com/q4m3/3_Lists/#325-simple-char-lists-and-strings - should set your mind at ease captain

Answer (score 2):

The code below should achieve what you want:

```
{@[`list1;x;{(-2_x),"ab"}]} where list2="B"
```

Output:

```
q){@[`list1;x;{(-2_x),"ab"}]} where list2="B"
`list1
q)list1
"Boy"
"Tab"
"Coy"
"Pab"
```